# Preserve position of elements in respect of background image while resize

Tags: javascript, css, svg, css-position

Hey I have container with background-image and I added the "pins" to the container and set the position. But the problem is with resize of the window. While the resizing the position of the pins doesnt preserve (especially vertically). How can I set the position to stay always on the same place in respect of background image ?

DEMO:
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qt0hbwjp/1/)

CSS:

```
.building {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  background: transparent url('http://svgshare.com/i/403.svg') no-repeat left center/contain;

  &__item {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 50;
    &--1 {
      bottom: 11%;
      left: 24%;
    }
    &--2 {
      bottom: 18%;
      left: 10%;
    }
    &--3 {
      bottom: 10%;
      left: 38%;
    }
    &--4 {
      bottom: 20%;
      left: 43%;
    }
    &--5 {
      bottom: 48%;
      left: 84%;
    }
    &--6 {
      bottom: 38%;
      left: 30%;
    }
    &--7 {
      bottom: 70%;
      left: 84%;
    }
    &--8 {
      bottom: 23%;
      left: 86%;
    }
    &--9 {
      bottom: 60%;
      left: 68%;
    }
    &--10 {
      bottom: 8%;
      left: 30%;
    }
    &--11 {
      bottom: 35%;
      left: 84%;
    }
  }
```

Comment: The easiest way would be to use an inline img instead of a background image. You can then add a wrapper element, such as a span, around your image  and position your pins relative to this instead of the outer 100% height/width wrapper. If you can't use an inline image, you'd have to use JavaScript to figure out the size of your background image based on the size of the wrapper and add an offset value to your pins, but that's a bit more work (for you and for the browser, as you'd have to attach a window resize event listener).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be able to accomplish this with pure CSS and `background-image` with sizing method set to `contain`.

You can however do pure CSS and use `<img />` tag to load the svg because Images keep proportions when scaled.

First you'll need to to add the `img` tag in the `.building`

Make your markers 0x0px wide and tall and give them negative margin offset by half the width and height.

That way the center of the marker will always be your anchor when your use percentages. (Provided you use top % and left %. In your case you use bottom % so you need to add 15px)

Set display of `.building` to `inline-block` -- that way it always "wraps around" the image.

You'll now have a responsive image that you can control the width of trough `.building{width:XX%}`

### [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/qt0hbwjp/2/)

```
.building {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;

  img{
    width:100%;
  }

  &__item {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 50;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    margin-left: -15px; //sub half of width
    margin-top: 15px; // add half of height
    ...
```

That's as far you'll get using pure CSS. For anything more advanced use jQuery and a [Responsive Hotspot Plugin](http://inabrains.com/tooltip/examples/image-hotspot.html)

Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

If you have the original width and height of the image and an initial position of your marker, you can calculate the new x position of the marker by doing this:

**newX = (initialX / originalWidth) * newWidth**

Same thing goes for the y position.

Here is a simple example using JS to recalculate the position, whenever the window resizes.

Let's stick the marker to the basketball ;)

```js
var img = new Image()
var wrapper = document.getElementsByClassName('wrapper-inner')[0]
var marker = document.getElementsByClassName('marker')[0]
var initialPos = {x:740, y:555}
var padding = 25
var imgW = 0
var imgH = 0

img.onload = function() {
  wrapper.firstElementChild.src = this.src
  imgW = this.width
  imgH = this.height
  resize()
}
img.src = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/9d/Finish_%28235964190%29.jpg/1024px-Finish_%28235964190%29.jpg'

function resize() {
    var imgRect = wrapper.getBoundingClientRect();
    marker.style.left = ((initialPos.x/imgW) * imgRect.width) - padding + "px"
    marker.style.top = ((initialPos.y/imgH) * imgRect.height) - padding + "px"
}
window.onresize = resize
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.wrapper {
  text-align: center;
}
.wrapper-inner {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 0;
  position: relative;
}
.wrapper-inner img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.marker {
  font-size: 32px;
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-radius: 25px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: white;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: +1;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="wrapper-inner">
    <img src="" alt="">
    <span class="marker">&starf;</span>
  </div>
</div>
```